# Not able launch Qt5 on ubuntu 14.04 multiple times.like we do in windows.right click and open another Qt5 application

Tags: qt, c++

recently I have installed Qt5 in my computer.I am not able to launch it multiple time.if I click on icon or if I right click and click open,it should give me separate another Qt5 application.but it isn't working.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CO0Mf.png)

Comment: Show us some code!

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is go to File -> session manager. And then click on new to create new session .During work you can easily switched between two sessions.

Answer (score 0):

I am only posting an answer for my question.we can run multiple projects in an single instance of an Qt application.Actually i wanted to run a client and server program simultaneously, so i was thinking i should launch to separator Qt Applications(the way i used to do in Windows 7). Now you can just open the project and do right click and select run.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apag7.png)